# Grid Updates (Row Editing) in Extjs takes more time when Number of records in the grid increases

Tags: javascript, extjs

As the number of records in the grid increases the time taken to update **one row** also increases.
Initially when I fetch 25 records the time taken to update is 2-3 seconds.
When I fetch 500 records on the same page time taken is 8-9 seconds.
Can anyone help me please so that I can avoid this. It is degrading the performance of the system.

```js
Ext.require([
    'Ext.grid.*',
    'Ext.data.*',
    'Ext.util.*',
    'Ext.state.*',
    'Ext.form.*'
]);

Ext.onReady(function(){
    // Define our data model
    Ext.define('Employee', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: [
            'name',
            'email',
            { name: 'start', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'n/j/Y' },
            { name: 'salary', type: 'float' },
            { name: 'active', type: 'bool' }
        ]
    });

    // Generate mock employee data
    var data = (function() {
        var lasts = ['Jones', 'Smith', 'Lee', 'Wilson', 'Black', 'Williams', 'Lewis', 'Johnson', 'Foot', 'Little', 'Vee', 'Train', 'Hot', 'Mutt'],
            firsts = ['Fred', 'Julie', 'Bill', 'Ted', 'Jack', 'John', 'Mark', 'Mike', 'Chris', 'Bob', 'Travis', 'Kelly', 'Sara'],
            lastLen = lasts.length,
            firstLen = firsts.length,
            usedNames = {},
            data = [],
            eDate = Ext.Date,
            now = new Date(),
            s = new Date(now.getFullYear() - 4, 0, 1),
            end = Ext.Date.subtract(now, Ext.Date.MONTH, 1),
            getRandomInt = Ext.Number.randomInt,

            generateName = function() {
                var name = firsts[getRandomInt(0, firstLen - 1)] + ' ' + lasts[getRandomInt(0, lastLen - 1)];
                if (usedNames[name]) {
                    return generateName();
                }
                usedNames[name] = true;
                return name;
            };

        while (s.getTime() < end) {
            var ecount = getRandomInt(0, 2);
            for (var i = 0; i < ecount; i++) {
                var name = generateName();
                data.push({
                    start : eDate.add(eDate.clearTime(s, true), eDate.DAY, getRandomInt(0, 27)),
                    name : name,
                    email: name.toLowerCase().replace(' ', '.') + '@sencha-test.com',
                    active: getRandomInt(0, 1),
                    salary: Math.floor(getRandomInt(35000, 85000) / 1000) * 1000
                });
            }
            s = eDate.add(s, eDate.MONTH, 1);
        }

        return data;
    })();

    // create the Data Store
    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        // destroy the store if the grid is destroyed
        autoDestroy: true,
        model: 'Employee',
        proxy: {
            type: 'memory'
        },
        data: data,
        sorters: [{
            property: 'start',
            direction: 'DESC'
        }]
    });

    var rowEditing = Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.RowEditing', {
        clicksToMoveEditor: 1,
        autoCancel: false
    });

    // create the grid and specify what field you want
    // to use for the editor at each column.
    var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        store: store,
        columns: [{
            header: 'Name',
            dataIndex: 'name',
            flex: 1,
            editor: {
                // defaults to textfield if no xtype is supplied
                allowBlank: false
            }
        }, {
            header: 'Email',
            dataIndex: 'email',
            width: 160,
            editor: {
                allowBlank: false,
                vtype: 'email'
            }
        }, {
            xtype: 'datecolumn',
            header: 'Start Date',
            dataIndex: 'start',
            width: 135,
            editor: {
                xtype: 'datefield',
                allowBlank: false,
                format: 'm/d/Y',
                minValue: '01/01/2006',
                minText: 'Cannot have a start date before the company existed!',
                maxValue: Ext.Date.format(new Date(), 'm/d/Y')
            }
        }, {
            xtype: 'numbercolumn',
            header: 'Salary',
            dataIndex: 'salary',
            format: '$0,0',
            width: 130,
            editor: {
                xtype: 'numberfield',
                allowBlank: false,
                minValue: 1,
                maxValue: 150000
            }
        }, {
            xtype: 'checkcolumn',
            header: 'Active?',
            dataIndex: 'active',
            width: 60,
            editor: {
                xtype: 'checkbox',
                cls: 'x-grid-checkheader-editor'
            }
        }],
        tbar: [{
            text: 'Add Employee',
            iconCls: 'employee-add',
            handler : function() {
                rowEditing.cancelEdit();

                // Create a model instance
                var r = Ext.create('Employee', {
                    name: 'New Guy',
                    email: 'new@sencha-test.com',
                    start: Ext.Date.clearTime(new Date()),
                    salary: 50000,
                    active: true
                });

                store.insert(0, r);
                rowEditing.startEdit(0, 0);
            }
        }, {
            itemId: 'removeEmployee',
            text: 'Remove Employee',
            iconCls: 'employee-remove',
            handler: function() {
                var sm = grid.getSelectionModel();
                rowEditing.cancelEdit();
                store.remove(sm.getSelection());
                if (store.getCount() > 0) {
                    sm.select(0);
                }
            },
            disabled: true
        }],
        plugins: [rowEditing],
        listeners: {
            'selectionchange': function(view, records) {
                grid.down('#removeEmployee').setDisabled(!records.length);
            }
        }
    });
    new Ext.window.Window({
        width: 900,
        height: 500,
        title: 'Employee Salaries',
        items: grid,
        layout: 'fit',
        closable: false
    }).show();
});
```

Comment: What you mean "update"? Render / refresh? 2-3 seconds for 25 rows is crazy. Something is wrong in your particular case. Post a fiddle.

Comment: Actually pagenation is applied.. and when I take 25 records/page the Update operation (Saving record in database) it takes 2-3 secs while for 500 records/page it takes 9-10 seconds. I can not share the exact code.. I am sorry.. :(

Comment: 2-3 seconds for 25 rows seems really long to me,  but I notice the same problem in my application. The time to update a row significantly increases with the number of rows in the grid. I'm not certain, but I think it is due to extjs redrawing the whole grid every time a row is updated. I'd like also to have better insight into this problem.

Comment: Your code might be unnecessarily saving all records on the page. If you want help on this you need to show some code. It does not need to be exactly the one your are working on — just reproduce the issue with some dummy example.

Comment: actually total there are around thousand records. But at a time on 1 page we are showing 25 records. So to fetch all those thousand records and make them fir 25 per page, it is taking 2-3 seconds. Is it too long? I am not sure.. But the main problem is with 500 records per page.. I will try to generate some dummy code

Comment: I have attached a code where in after I press Update button control goes to my controller. There I pass all the parameters that are to be updated to the stored procedure using a Map.I am using Spring. After that when records/page is 500 it takes time to load.

Comment: I think it is framwork issue as the same thing is running fine with 25 records/page.

Comment: I am doing record.commit() after I get the success message from the database. And that itself is taking almost 3 seconds.